# SharePoint Designer 2013 - setup a workflow to update items in a list from another list

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

I’m trying to create a workflow (2010 or 2013) to update all of the Department Names or the Department Codes in List 2 whenever there is change to the Department Names or Department Codes in List 1.

For example, if I update the department name ‘Operations Data’ to ‘Ops Data’ in List 1, I would like a workflow to loop through all the employee data in List 2 and update the department name to ‘Ops Data’.

What is the best way to accomplish this?

**List 1 – Depts & Codes (10-15 departments)**

Department Name     |    Department Code

Operations Data                1001
Operations Mgmt                  1002

**List 2 – Employee Data (800-900 employees)**

Employee Name    |   Position   |   Department Name   |     Department Code

John Doe                          Operator         Operations Data             1001
Tim Daily                         Operator         Operations Data             1001

Comment: Can you use a lookup column in List 2, referencing List 1? Lookup columns can bring over multiple columns of data and you should be able to get both your Department Name and Code pulled over (and updated) automatically doing it this way.

Comment: I'm able to use a lookup column because I need to be able to filter the items in the column.  Filtering lookup items does not work.

Comment: Correction - I'm **not** able to use a lookup column because I need to be able to filter the items in the column. Filtering lookup items does not work.

Answer (score 0):

On Item Update in Department List , Create workflow with  `loop` to do bulk update for all employees with `condition` Department = ‘Operations Data’

To know how to create this loop check [this](http://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/2012/10/24/create-sharepoint-2013-workflow-loop-by-using-sharepoint-2013-designer-preview-aspx-2/)